# How to find which processes caused the system slowdowns? To be used after reboot

Tags: linux, monitoring, cpu-usage, sysadmin

For the last few days my Ubuntu 16.04 suffers random slowdowns that it prevents the apps from loading and doesn't even allow me to connect via SSH.

The only way I can resolve it is by rebooting the server, but once I reboot I don't know what caused the issue.

I tried running htop but it doesn't help because that's realtime stats I want to see which processes were the ones causing the slowdown that left me with reboot as the only option to access the server again

Comment: Do you have enough memory in your machine? "free -m"

Comment: I think so: https://pastebin.com/XMdbLJZ1. But my main problem is that when the system slows down I can't even connect via SSH. So running free -m would not help as it shows real time stats. I want to know what's causing the huge CPU or ram usage before I have to reboot the server from the provider panel

Comment: What about Disk storage(hard disk)

Comment: You need a monitoring solution. There's hundreds, literally. New relic is probably easiest though